# rotating images using Source Editor 

Tags: html-editor, content-editor-web-part, imaging

I need the code for inserting a rotating banner image (banner that changes 2 or more images in the one spot). Does any body have this code?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:
http://armsinfragilehands.blogspot.com/2008/10/sharepoint-image-rotator.html